# Updating Netbeans C++ Makefile

Tags: c++, netbeans

I added some outside library files to my C++ project in netbeans within my Source folder. However the makefile doesnt seem to build them. I cant figure out how to add them to my makefile to have them included in the build. Has anyone done this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add it as *source files* or as *compiled library*?

- **Source files**: You need to add them to your Netbeans project (not only place them into the folder). Otherwise they aren't compiled when building it.
- **Compiled library:** This typically needs two settings: Add the library to the linker (`Build -> Linker -> Libraries`) and add the libraries header path to the include path (`Build -> C++ Compiler -> Include Directories`)